# Nand2Tetris Jump Directive Excpected

Tags: nand2tetris

I'm translating from .vm code to .asm code for project 7 but when I try to run the output code I get the error "in line 17, Jump directive expected"

```
    @7
    D=A
    @255
    M=D
    @8
    D=A
    @256
    M=D
    @256
    D=M
    @255
    M=M+D
    (END)
    @END
    0;jmp
```

It is referring to when I try to call the tag by saying @END but throws the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I had the same problem
In the last line shown, **"0;jmp"** is of the correct format, but the jump directive (jmp) has to be capitalized as in **"0;JMP"** or **"D;JNE"**